# Уведомление о новых сообщениях

Tags: java, android

Есть сайт. Там есть система сообщений.
Возможно ли как нибудь вывести на экран приложения количество новых сообщений? API у сайта нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если у сайта нет API, лучше его сделать.
В противном случае придётся работать с HTML (а это не надёжно) либо напрямую с MySQL (а это **крайне не безопасно**).

Comment: можно ли где нибудь найти примеры реализации подобного с HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с html можно взять [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html). Проще всего взять элемент по xpath.